# How to update product quantity stored in cookies in shopping cart?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have a list of products stored in cookies with the name **shopping_cart** as JSON.

What am I trying to do ?

I'm trying to update the product's quantity and save it to cookies. I couldn't come up with a way other than to remove all the cookies and create a new one (with the same name) with updated data.
The steps are :

1. Get cookies data and store it in a variable $items.
2. Loop through all items and check if one of them is the one to update its quantity by checking the hash_id related to it.
3. Delete the old cookie and create a new one with the same old name.

What is the problem that faces me?

The problem I have is the old session is not deleted ( after using:  **Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('shopping_cart'));**) and after executing the code the new updated products (quantity update) are created with old ones;

Example: The following example is the output of products that exist in cookie "shopping_cart" after json_decode and using "dd($cart_data);".

```
array:2 [▼
  4 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "727b8f0a-6925-4ecd-b9e0-3bc3e8a08a9a"
    "product_name" => "قميص جينز سادة جينز أزرق وسط22"
    "product_image" => "41d9f176-cacb-486b-a901-53ed0e67447d.jpg"
    "product_quantity" => "6"
    "product_price" => "7811"
    "original_price" => "7600.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▼
      "25a5b207-fe0f-482d-b6fc-3034f7db179e" => "bda60283-0490-4ed3-847c-39ec03f28796"
      "c8cc3ce4-fdd7-4368-9cf2-4bf5f5c24497" => "d2290947-5e5d-4d02-8f02-19c8269698bd"
    ]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$qwRmwtxBHqnAS4ef.no1i.x/.zVbG4gmyz0e3laq86eqS94JbUMmu"
  ]
  5 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "cd048d7f-462a-40ac-b9ed-49a8c499da06"
    "product_name" => "الحذاء الرياضي تشارجد كوميت 2 أسود / أبيض"
    "product_image" => "1625987228.png"
    "product_quantity" => "1"
    "product_price" => "4400"
    "original_price" => "4000.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▼
      "f015fee9-1e17-447c-bb12-6f6f55588001" => "2be4e09b-62a8-47bf-bba1-257fbab55cce"
      "8d318964-09ca-4770-9dd5-c75ff29f03cb" => "5864acfd-c0fd-498f-bdd6-6b6615eabb65"
    ]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$0PZobkhbEJsdf52n0f2HSertloWiQOHchFOCqgGbLr9itc.nAt4SG"
  ]
]
```

My code to update product quantity:

```
  if (Cookie::get('shopping_cart')) {
            $cookie_data = stripslashes(Cookie::get('shopping_cart'));

            $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);


            $quantity = $request->quantity;
            $hash_id = $request->hash_id;

            $items = $cart_data;


            $productsArray = [];
            foreach ($items as $item) {

                if ($item['hash_id'] == $hash_id)
                {
                    $productsArray[] = [
                        'product_uuid' => $item['product_uuid'],
                        'product_name' => $item['product_name'],
                        'product_image' => $item['product_image'],
                        'product_quantity' => $quantity,
                        'product_price' => $item['product_price'],
                        'original_price' => $item['original_price'],
                        'attributes' => $item['attributes'],
                        'hash_id' => $item['hash_id'],
                    ];

                }
                if ($item['hash_id'] != $hash_id)
                {
                    $productsArray[] = [
                        'product_uuid' => $item['product_uuid'],
                        'product_name' => $item['product_name'],
                        'product_image' => $item['product_image'],
                        'product_quantity' =>  $item['product_quantity'],
                        'product_price' => $item['product_price'],
                        'original_price' => $item['original_price'],
                        'attributes' => $item['attributes'],
                        'hash_id' => $item['hash_id'],
                    ];
                }

            }


            Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('shopping_cart'));

            foreach ($productsArray as $product)
            {

                $cart_data[] = $product;

                $product_data = json_encode($cart_data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('shopping_cart', $product_data,7200));
            }

            $totalcart = count($cart_data);

            $order = "";
            return view('guest.cart.index', compact('cart_data', 'totalcart','order'));
        }
```

Result after code execution :

```
array:4 [▼
  4 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "727b8f0a-6925-4ecd-b9e0-3bc3e8a08a9a"
    "product_name" => "قميص جينز سادة جينز أزرق وسط22"
    "product_image" => "41d9f176-cacb-486b-a901-53ed0e67447d.jpg"
    "product_quantity" => "6"
    "product_price" => "7811"
    "original_price" => "7600.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▶]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$qwRmwtxBHqnAS4ef.no1i.x/.zVbG4gmyz0e3laq86eqS94JbUMmu"
  ]
  5 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "cd048d7f-462a-40ac-b9ed-49a8c499da06"
    "product_name" => "الحذاء الرياضي تشارجد كوميت 2 أسود / أبيض"
    "product_image" => "1625987228.png"
    "product_quantity" => "1"
    "product_price" => "4400"
    "original_price" => "4000.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▶]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$0PZobkhbEJsdf52n0f2HSertloWiQOHchFOCqgGbLr9itc.nAt4SG"
  ]
  6 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "727b8f0a-6925-4ecd-b9e0-3bc3e8a08a9a"
    "product_name" => "قميص جينز سادة جينز أزرق وسط22"
    "product_image" => "41d9f176-cacb-486b-a901-53ed0e67447d.jpg"
    "product_quantity" => "8"
    "product_price" => "7811"
    "original_price" => "7600.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▶]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$qwRmwtxBHqnAS4ef.no1i.x/.zVbG4gmyz0e3laq86eqS94JbUMmu"
  ]
  7 => array:8 [▼
    "product_uuid" => "cd048d7f-462a-40ac-b9ed-49a8c499da06"
    "product_name" => "الحذاء الرياضي تشارجد كوميت 2 أسود / أبيض"
    "product_image" => "1625987228.png"
    "product_quantity" => "1"
    "product_price" => "4400"
    "original_price" => "4000.00"
    "attributes" => array:2 [▶]
    "hash_id" => "$2y$10$0PZobkhbEJsdf52n0f2HSertloWiQOHchFOCqgGbLr9itc.nAt4SG"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error that caused me such a problem. It's because I repeated the variable $cart_data and forgot to change it before saving the new items to cookies and the solution was to just change the variable name.